# How to assert a collection is a child of other collection using fluent-assertions?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I want to test a method returning collection using fluent-assertions to ensure that returned collection is a child of other collection, I tried `fatherCollection.Should().Contain(childCollection);` but not work. How to do that?

Comment: Can you provide a sample data?  that would be a great help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collection.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(item)` on each of the items in the child collection.

Comment: Wrap it with `AssertionScope` and failed message will include all failed items, not only first one.